# What is your go-to solution for EU cookie consent requirements in 2022?

Tags: magento2, cookie, gdpr

EU's GDPR cookie consent requirements are pretty strict. I have not been able to find a fully compliant extension or service to satisfy all the requirements the legislation sets.

All extensions seem to miss proper consent log that also logs the guest visitors and set's a suitable ID or other method of identification so that connection can be made between cookie and the consent.

Then there is the requirement that no cookie can't be set before consent is given. This seems difficult to achieve.

There are more requirements of course, but what is your go-to solution that has ALL the required functions?

Comment: After some digging I decided to try the Cookiefirst and it seems to work and it blocks all cookies until they are accepted.